# What is the use of PHP function is_int()?

Tags: php, function, logic

I just wonder why php have a function like `is_int()`. Documentation says that

> To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string  (such as form input, which is always a string)

I am sure that no one will ever have to check the  type of a variable that is statically assigned. So someone please tell me will there be any situation, where the function `is_int()` really useful ?

Comment: `such as form input`: this is not statically assigned. The user could type `3` (integer) or `3.5` (float).

Comment: @Antony: but for all the user input from form elements, it will return false, since it is considered as string ( for `3` and `3.5`)

Answer (score 1):

complete understding soluation....

this is code

```
 <?php
  $values = array(23, "23", 23.5, "23.5", null, true, false);
  foreach ($values as $value) {
   echo "is_int(";
  var_export($value);
    echo ") = ";
       var_dump(is_int($value));
     }
       ?>
```

this is output

```
     is_int(23) = bool(true)
     is_int('23') = bool(false)
    is_int(23.5) = bool(false) 
   is_int('23.5') = bool(false) 
     is_int(NULL) = bool(false)
    is_int(true) = bool(false)
      is_int(false) = bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a user form input:

```
$_POST['integer'] = "3";
$integer = +$_POST['integer']; // convert to a number
var_dump(is_int($integer)); // bool(true)

$_POST['float'] = "3.5";
$float = +$_POST['float']; // convert to a number
var_dump(is_int($float)); // bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can be useful in the following scenario,

```
$a = 5;


//some functionality
function passbyref(&$b)
{
    $b = "45";
}


passbyref($a);


if(is_int($a))
{
   print "Yes it is int";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It finds whether the type of the given variable is `integer` or not.

This is the example I found :

```
$values = array(23, "23", 23.5, "23.5", null, true, false);
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        echo "is_int(";
        var_export($value);
        echo ") = ";
        var_dump(is_int($value));
    }
```

The above example will output:

```
is_int(23) = bool(true)
is_int('23') = bool(false)
is_int(23.5) = bool(false)
is_int('23.5') = bool(false)
is_int(NULL) = bool(false)
is_int(true) = bool(false)
is_int(false) = bool(false)
```

To understand more : [Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)